# Can't store custom data in child NSManagedObject with Xcode 10.2.1

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swift5, xcode10.2

I updated Xcode to 10.2.1 and noticed that I can't init and store any custom properties in child NSManagedObject class (It worked in previous Xcode version). Is anybody has the same problem?

I created new project. If I'll create ONE parent and ONE child entity. I able to store custom data ONLY in parent entity but if I'll store some custom class in child one, the property will be always nil.

Here is parent entity:

```
@objc(Entity)
public class Entity: NSManagedObject {

    class var entityName: String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }

    private var testClass = MyTestClass()

    init() {
        let entityName: String = type(of: self).entityName
        let context: NSManagedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        guard let entityDescription: NSEntityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: entityName, in: context) else {
            fatalError("Failed to create entity description for name: \(entityName)")
        }
        super.init(entity: entityDescription, insertInto: context)

        print(testClass.testProperty)
    }
}

extension Entity {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Entity> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Entity>(entityName: "Entity")
    }

    @NSManaged public var title: String?

}
```

Here is child entity:

```
@objc(EntityChild)
public class EntityChild: Entity {

    private var testClassChild = MyTestClass()

    override init() {
        super.init()

        print(testClassChild.testProperty)//on this line app will crash
    }
}

extension EntityChild {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<EntityChild> {
        return NSFetchRequest<EntityChild>(entityName: "EntityChild")
    }

    @NSManaged public var title2: String?

}
```

Also attaching screenshots of code execution:

[image: Prent entity]

[image: Child entity]

**Note**

it works as expected if use property as `lazy` or if add properties as force unwrapped and initialize them in `init`

Comment: Hello, Misha.  Your question is very inconvenient to read and search because it has screenshots of code in Xcode.  Please consider editing your question – remove the screenshots and replace with [code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: Hi @JerryKrinock, I also attache the code blocks of child and parent entities

Comment: Comment 1.  I don't think you should override `NSManagedObject.init()`  Although [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject) does no explicitly disallow this, they don't even mention it, and I've never seen this done.  Getting "creative" with Core Data rarely results in anything that works.

Comment: Comment 2.  Your `EntityChild` is a subclass of `Entity` which is a subclass of `NSManagedObject`.  Again, I've never seen that done, and I cannot think of any reason to do that.  The conventional approach is to create an *Entity* in your *data model* for each type of object you need in your object graph, and have one corresponding subclass of `NSManagedObject` for each entity.

Comment: Comment 3.  I think you should tell us briefly what kind of app you are trying to build, what you expect this app to do, and probably someone can point you to some sample code or tutorial so you can get re-started on the correct path.  Working with Core Data is somewhat different than plain object-oriented programming.  You start with a data model.

Comment: *Regarding 1 comment*:
I didn't overridde  `NSManagedObject.init()`, I created my own.  If you will check parent entity, you'll see that I used `super.init(entity: entityDescription, insertInto: context)`.
*2 commen*t:
I did this not manually, but in `xcdatamodeld`. Also in my real project CoreData is much complicated, the code above it's just example, I can't share the project example, since I signed NDA
*Comment 3*:
As I said the real project is much complicated, there a lot of dependencies and relation. The issue that in previous Xcode example above worked, but in Xcode 10.2 it's not

Comment: Comment 1, again.  OK, I see what you mean.  It is probably true that Core Data does not call init().  If it is true that only your code calls init(), then you are OK.  But whether or not this happens is a iOS or macOS implementation detail not under your control, and naming your method init() is asking for trouble.  You should change that symbol name.

Comment: Comment 2, again.  You are correct.  I did not realize that was a file generated by Xcode.  I thought it was your code, and I forgot that Xcode does create subclasses of parent classes for child entities.  If it is true, as you say, that it is the Xcode version update which caused the problem for you, then you should compare your new and old Xcode-generated files and you may get a clue to the problem.

Comment: Comment 1: I removed my custom init, and did initialization in the view controller. Unfortunately  getting the same issue

Comment: Comment 2: I compared old and new generated files. They are the same